# passing values from python to html using flask and echart

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to pass two lists from a .py file to html to create a chart using html show on the web

The xxx.py file's code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/conn',methods=['POST'])
def conn():
    table_name = request.form['table_name']  
    start_date = request.form['start_date']
    end_date = request.form['end_date']
    data1 = postgresql.PostgreSql(table_name,start_date,end_date)
    data1.rfm_chart()
    segment = data1.rfm['Segment'].value_counts().to_dict()
    return render_template('chart.html', **segment)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

segment's output: {'A':100, 'B':50, 'C':25, 'D':18}

And Here is the chart.html:

```
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

    var option = {
        title: {
            text: 'RFM'
        },
        tooltip: {},
        legend: {
            data:['Number of players']
        },
        xAxis: {
            data: {{  }}
        },
        yAxis: {},
        series: [{
            name: '#Players',
            type: 'bar',
            data: {{  }}
        }]
    };

    myChart.setOption(option);
</script>
```

I want keys of segment to be the x axis and values as y axis. But how can I pass the dict from .py to html?

Comment: Read about  Flask rendering templates https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, just use `tojson` filter like

```
data: {{ series_data|tojson }}
```

You need to change `series_data` to the key of `segment` that you need to use.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#tojson